# How to merge 3 tables in SQLite and get the range of dates of the resulting table with groupby

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have 3 tables in `SQLite`:

```
Category_tbl:

      Id Name
      1    A
      2    B
      3    C


brand_tbl:

   RespondentId  CategoryId BrandId
             1           1     br1
             2           2     br2
             3           3     br3

resp_tbl:

   CategoryId  RespondentId       Date
           1             1  2019-01-02
           2             2  2019-01-03
```

What I would like to do, is to inner join all 3 of them:

- the `category_tbl` with `brand_tbl` on the `Id` and `CategoryId` respectively
- and the `result` of this with the `rest_tbl` on `CategoryId` and `RespondentId`

and then get the min and the max `Date` by `CategoryId` and `BrandId`

Is there a neat and compact way to this in SQLite ?

My expected output should like this:

```
CategoryId  Name   BrandId max_date     min_date    
1            A         br1 2019-01-02   2019-01-02
2            B         br2 2019-01-03   2019-01-03
```

Comment: provide your expected output in table format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below -

```
    select a.categoryid,name,BrandId,min(Date) as min_date,max(date) as max_date
    from resp_tbl a 
       inner join brand_tbl b on a.categoryid=b.CategoryId and a.RespondentId=b.RespondentId
       inner join Category_tbl c on a.categoryid=c.id
    group by a.categoryid,name,BrandId
```